# Power BI Embedded current bookmark state not wroking

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to export to a pdf file a power bi embedded report. I want to export current values that the user has selected. For that purporse the documentation advise to use this functionality [Power BI Export in current state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to#bookmarks), when I use the `let capturedBookmark = report.bookmarksManager.capture();` function this error shows to me:

> message: "captureBookmarkFailed", detailedMessage: "Invalid bookmark request", level: 3.

So I was wondering if anybody had the same error and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of your [powerbi-client](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) package.

In my case I found that an environment running version `2.15.1` was raising this exception.

Not sure what the problem is with this version, but if you explicitly update your `package.json` to `2.14.1` the problem seems to disappear:

```
"powerbi-client": "2.14.1"
```